# Apollo: Using same objectID with different depth of query

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

Let's say I have 2 pages. `User` and `UserDetail`.

`User` is wrapped by just

```
user (id: 1){
 id
 name
 email
}
```

whereas `UserDetail` is wrapped by more detail query

```
user (id: 1) {
 id
 name
 email
 bankAccount
 ...
}
```

I setup `dataIdFromObject` as typename + id so in this case, both of them use the key of `User-1`

1. When I switch from page User to UserDetail, will`User-1` in apollo cache be overwritten to have `bankAccount` data?
2. When I switch from UserDetail to User, will `bankAccount` be removed?
3. Is it common approach for apollo dataId to be used this way (duplicately) across different pages with different depth of data?